# 管理者権限の必要なコマンドを Swift から実行するには？

Tags: swift, macos

現在は以下のようにして実行しているのですが、パスワードが間違っていた時にアプリケーションが固まってしまいます。

swift

```
let task = NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath("/bin/sh", arguments: ["-c","/AAAA.sh","sleep 3"])
 task.waitUntilExit()
```

AAAA.sh

```
echo "パスワード" | sudo -S apachectl start
```

これを回避するために、

- 事前にパスワードを確かめる方法
- sudoの失敗を検知する方法

のどちらかを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 「管理者権限の必要なコマンドを実行したい」というのが本題と思われたので、勝手ながら質問を再編させていただきました。もし間違った内容になっていたらご指摘いただくか、お手数ですが再度編集をお願いします。

Comment: おそらくsudoがパスワードチェックでNGを出した場合、エラーとならずパスワードの再入力を要求している可能性があり・・・。　その場合、呼び出されたマクロから制御が呼び出し元のアプリに戻らないので固まるのではないかと考えます。　なので、パスワードの確認方法が知りたいです。

Comment: 私の環境では再現できませんでした。パスワードが間違っていても終了します。sudoの出力を貼っていただけますか？

Comment: 自分が何かミスしているのかな？再度、確認してみます。
パスワードが間違っていても正常終了のような感じで戻ってきているのでしょうか？　その場合エラーしている事はSwiftで確認できるのでしょうか？

Comment: 確認しました。　パスワードが間違っても呼び出し元に制御は戻るみたいです。
すみません。　ただ、最初の質問どおりエラーしている事を知る方法がわかりません。　事前パスワードチェックを可能とするか、マクロの実行終了後エラーしていないかをSwiftでわかる方法がわかりません。　宜しくお願いします

Answer (score 1):

シェルスクリプトの実行に成功したかどうかは、`terminationStatus`を調べれば分かります。
ただ、これだけだとパスワードが間違っていたのかその後のコマンドの実行に失敗したのかが判断できません。

```
let task = NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath("/bin/sh", arguments: ["-c","/AAAA.sh"])
task.waitUntilExit()

if task.terminationStatus != 0 {
    // 失敗
}
```

パスワードが間違っているかどうか最初に判断したいなら、先にダミーの`sudo`だけを実行して`terminationStatus`を調べるという方法でどうでしょうか？

```
echo "パスワード" | sudo -S true
```

Comment: sudoが成功するとしばらくはパスワード不要になるので `-k` を付ける方が妥当なような気がします。